# How to uninstall python3.6.3 (installed from source)

Tags: uninstall, python3

So, I got myself in some trouble. I installed python3.6.3 from source. I'm not a programmer or anything, I was just curious to see if I could do it.

Now I'm unable to run catfish. I get this message from the terminal:

```
enriken@Frankie-II ~ $ catfish
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/catfish/bin/catfish.py", line 22, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

My guess is that this problem is caused by having installed python3.6.3.

I installed it with these commands:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Comment: Most likely you just need to change what /usr/bin/python points to. What do you get when you run `ls -l /usr/bin/python`?

Comment: ^ What @amanusk said. Also try `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`, and `type python python3` just in case the binary is elsewhere.

Comment: I ran the commands, this is what I got

`ls -l /usr/bin/python` returned  `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 14  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7`

 and `ls -l /usr/bin/python3` returned `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 14  2015 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4`

Comment: Also try 'which python3' to see if your python3 is chosen before the python3 in /usr/bin. You might also check the beginning of the catfish.py file for a line that begins with '#!'. This identifies the python that should be run. If that line is simply '#!python3', then your newly installed Python may be getting run. If that is the case, you may be able to modify your PATH to put /usr/local/bin after /usr/bin.

Comment: I believe that installing python from source will install it in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: The first line in the catfish file goes:

` #!/usr/bin/env python `

In ` /usr/local/bin/ ` there are a few python3.6 files, deleting those gets rid of python3.6?

Comment: @enriken Woah woah woah, don't delete anything. We don't have enough info yet. Run `type python python3` first.

Comment: So, ` type python python3 ` returned this: ` python is /usr/bin/python   python3 is /usr/bin/python3 `

Comment: @enriken Unfortunately, I can't be much more help since I've never installed Python from source myself. But I suggest you [edit] your question to add all this info, which will make it easier for others to help you. (And editing the question will bump it to the homepage.)